# Can't get rid of IIS 7.5

Tags: iis

I am trying to get rid of IIS 7.5 so that I can use WAMP, because I have to write an app that uses a MySQL database (ugh, if I have to I suppose I can use one of my web servers).

I've uninstalled IIS express in control panel, and I've also removed IIS from the installed windows services.

I am running Windows 7 and my localhost is still giving me the IIS welcome page. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not just run IIS or Apache on a different port?

Comment: How would I change that?

Comment: You've definitely removed IIS from the Programs and Features section? Maybe you're looking at a cached copy of the page, tried clearing your cache? Also try a netstat -ao to see if anything is listening on port 80

Comment: You can change Apache's default port by editing the config file. IIS is a little trickier because you use the UI to do so, but there are many resources accessible through a search engine to aid you. I brought it up as a possibility because you seem to be using a hammer to solve a problem that needs a screwdriver (if you'll pardon the metaphor).

Comment: 0:0:0:0 is listening to 80